# What does "ma i te na" mean in japanese?

Tags: slang

may be I mistaken in romaji

here what I mean

http://youtu.be/bS-oT9nONxw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

参ったなぁ
Maitta naa

It's generally an exclamation of negative emotion/giving up. Take a look at the [example sentences here](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%8F%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F&ref=sa) to get a better idea.